# Windows 6CE app on Windows 7CE device

Tags: .net, vb.net

Developed app on VS 2008 in .net for platform Windows 6CE.

Now when i bought device which has 7CE OS on it my app is not working and not able to set up.

How can i fix this.

Do i need to change this 
[image]

Comment: We need Code, errors expected behaviour, actual behaviour please. Have a torough read  of these articles  .. [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @DavidWilson Where i can change target OS to be available on Windows 7CE